# About the Qiskit draw function

Tags: programming, qiskit

Where does Qiskit put the rendered figure created by `circuit.draw(output='mpl')`?

Comment: Are you asking this question because when you run a program with `circuit.draw(output='mpl')`, the rendered Figure does not show up? Does it look like a new window appears and then instantly closes? Also, are you running this in Jupyter Notebooks or locally in the terminal?

I have an answer for both just want to make sure I don't post an answer that doesn't apply to the method you are using.

Comment: Yes nothing shows up, in the meantimei don't think i have installed anything related to that. i run code from  the terminal

Comment: Ok I will answer in regards to this use case then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Qiskit does not save the rendered `Figure` of the circuit anywhere, unless you provide a `filename` to the call.

For example: `circuit.draw(filename='<file_path>')`.

In regards to having the `Figure` render and stay open, you simply need to remove a line of code. If you go to where qiskit is installed in your environment, go into the file `qiskit/visualization/matplotlib.py`, and go to line 436 you will see the line `plt.close(self.figure)`. Comment this line out, and run your program again. You should see the `Figure` in a new window.

Comment: What's the supported file types for the file option ?

Comment: I'm not sure of all of the supported file types, but I know that `.png`, `.pdf`, and `.svg` should be supported considering `matplotlib` uses them as examples on their [documentation page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure)

Answer (score 1):

You should add interactive argument, if you want to see the figure, example:

```
qubit.draw(output='mpl', fold=50, interactive= True)
```